# How to pass a prop to an imported function that returns a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass an argument back to my component library that is imported in a parent app as a dependency, but I am not entirely sure how to achieve this and I was hoping somebody could tell me what am I doing wrong. The idea is that on customer login we will determine which brand are they with and switch the theme that should be used going forward (I added a simplified example rendering a `SpecialComponent`)

Currently I have a Theme object in my component library that returns a Theme component wrapped in ThemeProvider. This was working fine until I tried to expand the concept of the theme object and add a concept of a brand.

Here is my `Theme.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

export const theme = config => {
  const Theme = (props) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={config}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
  Theme.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
  };
  return Theme;
};

const LightThemes = {
    Adidas: {
        name: 'Light',
        variant: 'white',
        background: 'red',
        color: 'green',
        textColor: 'white'
    },
    Nike: {
        name: 'Light',
        variant: 'red',
        background: 'black',
        color: 'yellow',
        textColor: 'black'
    }
};

const Light = ({ brand }) => theme(LightThemes[brand]);

const Theme = {
  Light
};

export default Theme;
```

And here is how I am calling it within my app:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SpecialComponent,
  Theme
} from '@my-component-library';

const App = () => (
  <Theme.Light brand={'Adidas'}>
    <SpecialComponent />
  </Theme.Light>
);

export default App;
```

As you can see I am trying to pass the string of `Adidas` to `<Theme.Light>` however this doesn't work and I get an error back saying `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.`.

Before I added the concept of a brand in, my Theme.js looked like this and it was working fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

export const theme = config => {
  const Theme = (props) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={config}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
  Theme.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
  };
  return Theme;
};

const LightThemes = {
    name: 'Light',
    variant: 'white',
    background: 'red',
    color: 'green',
    textColor: 'white'
};

const Light = theme(LightThemes);

const Theme = {
  Light
};

export default Theme;
```

I believe this is because previously I had a HOC and now that became a function that returns a component, so I can't use it in the same way that I used in the past. I am struggling to understand how to do this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's right there in the error. `Theme.Light` is a function, not a component, meaning that the way to make it work is with `Theme.Light({ brand: 'BrandName' })`.

This might help:

```js
const lightCmp = Theme.Light({ brand: 'Adidas' });

const App = () => (
  <lightCmp>
    <SpecialComponent />
  </lightCmp>
);
```

EDIT:

The reason it worked before is because to `Light` you are assigning the return of `theme()` which is a component, in your new version you need to instantiate the function first. Basically, you're doing the same thing with an extra step.

Another solution could be to have a hook `useTheme({ brand })` that returns a HoC component.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes total sense! Have you got any articles you could link on how to write a hook that returns a HOC? I thought hooks were meant to replace HOCs?

Comment: Yea and no, hooks are (but not only) a replacement to class inheritance and allowing (in a way) to have lifecycle hooks (hence the name) in functional programming. Alternatively, you could write your own Context using `useContext` as a higher order function to styled-components context. Unfortunately, I don't have any articles or literature with this.